# Python Classes Inheritance

Tags: python, class, inheritance, method-resolution-order

I am having a bit trouble understanding python's mro(Method resolution order). Python operates from left to right. So as per my understanding the order of calling for M should be.
M, B, A, Z, X, Y

```
class X: pass
class Y: pass
class Z: pass

class A(X,Y): pass
class B(Y,Z): pass

class M(B,A,Z): pass

print(M.mro())
```

But the correct order of calling is.

```
    [<class '__main__.M'>,
 <class '__main__.B'>,
 <class '__main__.A'>,
 <class '__main__.X'>,
 <class '__main__.Y'>,
 <class '__main__.Z'>,
 <class 'object'>]
```

Can anyone explain the ordering and help me understand this. Thank you

Comment: _Python operates from left to right_: no, it does not. It implements [C3 linearization algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization)

Answer (score 2):

mro has been based on C3 algorithm since Python2.3, and 'merge' is core of that algorithm. [how merge works](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/).
According to your code, here we can list how to get mro(M):

```
mro(M) = [M] + merge(mro(B), mro(A), mro(Z), [B,A,Z])    

mro(B) = [B] + merge(mro(Y) , mro(Z)) = [B] + merge([Y] , [Z])
       = [B,Y] + merge([Z]) 
       = [B,Y,Z]

mro(A) = [A] + merge(mro(X) , mro(Y)) 
       = [A] + merge([X],[Y]) 
       = [A,X,Y]

mro(Z) = [Z]
```

Back to `mro(M)`:

```
mro(M) = [M] + merge([B,Y,Z), [A,X,Y], [Z], [B,A,Z]) 
       = [M,B] + merge([Y,Z], [A,X,Y], [Z], [A,Z]) 
       = [M,B,A] + merge([Y,Z], [X,Y], [Z], [Z]) 
       = [M,B,A,X] + merge([Y,Z] + [Y] + [Z], [Z]) 
       = [M,B,A,X,Y] + merge([Z] + [Z] + [Z]) 
       = [M,B,A,X,Y,Z]
```